# How to access host nodejs app from docker nuxt app?

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu, nuxt.js, web-deployment

I am trying to get my nuxt app working on the production servers. For the local machine, the generated docker image runs well and it can access the nodejs app that runs on localhost. The axios 'baseurl: [http://127.0.0.1:6008/'](http://127.0.0.1:6008/%27) seems working fine, the docker image can access this. On the production servers, i have used docker to setup the nuxt app, the same way i tested on my local machine. Yet the docker nuxt app cannot reach the nodejs app on the host server. I can see this must be some kind of network setting issue.

In vuejs app, i usually setup a proxypass in the apache web conf, to convert the input backend query to match and replace them with localhost address.

```
ProxyPass /app/query http://localhost:6008/query
```

The nuxt.config file, axios setting looks lik this:

```
axios: {
baseURL:'http://127.0.0.1:6008/',
browserBaseURL: ''
},
```

Does docker needs additional settings or should i configure my apache for this communication between my docker container and a node app that running on host apache pm2 ?

Comment: In localhost bridge network is used, so by default all containers will be on the same network which can be accessed by localhost, are you using same network config (default) in your production as well, or are creating different virtual networks for them? (If you are using docker compose and added them as different services, they will be on different virtual networks)

Comment: Yes i use the default setting in all location. Have not built any virtual networks between the localhost and the docker.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` or `127.0.0.1` from within the docker will not resolve to the server's localhost. Instead you need to specify the name of the nodejs service (if you are using docker-compose) or the nodejs docker container name (if you are just using docker run).

You can also try by giving the IP of the server where the docker is running instead of `127.0.0.1`